# How do I display inline content with the Colorbox Module?

Tags: javascript

I understand that I need to add the class "colorbox-inline" to the link and build the url like 119 this "?width=500&height=500&inline=true#id-of-content"... but how do I do that? Do I need to edit a .tpl file?

Answer (score 5):

No PHP, this is done with HTML and JavaScript

1. CSS style the inline-content you want to display with "display: none;"
2. for colorbox: in "configuration", "Media", "Colorbox" --> advanced settings,
   activate "Enable Colorbox inline"
3. add this as the html code for opening the colorbox webform link: `<a class="colorbox-inline" href="?width=310&amp;height=460&amp;inline=true#name-of-your-inline-content">`
4. If this is not working try some additionally jQuery-Magic: `$('#name-of-your-inline-content').colorbox();`

Comment: Where exactly should this code be added? @headkit

Re: add this as the html code for opening the colorbox webform link: <a class="colorbox-inline" href="?width=310&amp;height=460&amp;inline=true#name-of-your-inline-content">

Comment: @headkit Where do I specify "name-of-your-inline-content"?